# I want to search Ö this character in list

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to check out the android api level in html css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use unicode character for your problem

here is the table for some character with equivalent unicode character.

```
Ä, ä        \u00c4, \u00e4
Ö, ö        \u00d6, \u00f6
Ü, ü        \u00dc, \u00fc
ß           \u00df
```